# Creating a python Rectangle object class that can print the corner coordinates

Tags: python, object, position

I am new to python. I need to create a python `Rectangle` object class that when called upon one can print the coordinates of the corners as well as have the area and perimeter. I am having issues when I try to run my code that says:

```
<__main__.Rectangle instance at 0x02F20030>
```

I was told to add the `__str__` as well but then I get:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```python
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight):
        self.tL = topLeft
        self.tR = topRight
        self.bL = bottomLeft
        self.bR = bottomRight
    def perim(self):
            return (2 * (self.tL + self.tR)) + (2 * (self.bL + self.bR))
    def area(self):
            return (self.tL + self.tR) * (self.bL + self.bR)
    def position(self):
        return self.tL
        return self.tR
        return self.bL
        return self.bR
def __repr__(self):
        return self.tL
        return self.tR
        return self.bL
        return self.bT


r1 = Rectangle (5, 5, 10, 10)
print r1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'tL = '+str(self.tL) + ', tR ='+ str(self.tR)+', bL ='+ str(self.bL) + ', bR =' +str(self.bR)
```

notes:

- make only one `return` statement execute in a function, in your code your function only returns self.bT (the last).
- In the provided code `def __repr__(self)` is not indented.
- you don't need 4 points to define a rectangle.
- your Rectangle corners shouldn't just be integers, they have to be sequences of two coordinates (x, y) for instance (3, 7) is a point, implement a point as a 2 integers tuple or list.

edit:
as the OP asked, here's how to change your `__init__` method to work with cartesian coordinates:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, tL, bR):  #tL and bR should be passed as tuples
        self.tL = tL
        self.tR = (bR[0], tL[1])  #access tuple elements with tuple[index]
        self.bL = (bR[1], tL[0])
        self.bR = bR

        self.width = bR[0]- tL[0]
        self.height = bR[1] - tL[1]
    def area(self):
        #get area
        #...
    def perim(self):
        #get perim
        #...

r1 = Rectangle((5,5), (30, 20))
print r1.tL   #output (5, 5)
print r1.tR   #output (30, 5)
print r1.width #output 25
print r1.area() #output 375
```

of course you can create a Point `class` instead of that, and then you pass two `Point`s to  `__init__` to define the rectangle.

I hope that helped you!

Comment: How do I get my code to accept Cartesian coordinates? If I try to insert coordinates as tuples or lists into my r1 = Rectangle(..) I get an argument error message.

Comment: @MaryKate I edited my answer to include that, please accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, functions cannot have more than one return statement.

Also, `def __repr__(self):` is not correctly indented (it belongs to the Rectangle class).

You might prefer `__str__` over `__repr__`, see [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for more details.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight):
        self.tL = topLeft
        self.tR = topRight
        self.bL = bottomLeft
        self.bR = bottomRight
    def perim(self):
        return (2 * (self.tL + self.tR)) + (2 * (self.bL + self.bR))
    def area(self):
        return (self.tL + self.tR) * (self.bL + self.bR)
    def position(self):
        return (self.tL, self.tR, self.bL, self.bR)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Rectangle(%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (self.tL, self.tR, self.bL, self.bR)

r1 = Rectangle (5, 5, 10, 10)
print r1
print "Perimeter: %s" % r1.perim()
print "Area: %s" % r1.area()
print "Position: (%s, %s, %s, %s)" % r1.position()
```