# How do I pass two Points to __init__ to define a rectangle?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

How do I create an  `__init__` method that takes two objects of type point as input (bottom left corner and top right corner) and a string for color

i.e.

```
r1= Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(1,1), 'blue')
r1.get_bottom_left() --> Point(0,0)
```

So far I have:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, PointbL, PointtR, 'color'):
         self.bL = PointbL
         self.tR = PointtR
         self.bLx= PointbL[0]
         self.bLy= PointbL[1]
         self.tRx= PointtR[0]
         Self.tRy= PointtR[1]
         self.color='color'
```

I just learned about class methods and so I am unsure on how to do this but this looks wrong to me... I tried to figure it out with answers from the following question posted but I don't think I did it right

[Creating a python Rectangle object class that can print the corner coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362455/creating-a-python-rectangle-object-class-that-can-print-the-corner-coordinates)

Comment: "it looks wrong" - have you tried if it works?

Comment: What you've shown does what you're asking for. We have no idea what *else* you might want, so there's not much more we can help you with. Do you have an actual issue that you can ask a question about?

Comment: @Blckknght Yes,  I get a TypeError: 'Point' object does not support indexing

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I get a TypeError: 'Point' object does not support indexing

Comment: That error seems pretty self explanatory. The `Point` class' interface doesn't allow expressions like `PointbL[0]`. You need to do something else. Maybe use an attribute, like `PointbL.x`? I have no idea where your `Point` class comes from, so I can't tell you for sure. I will note that it's a bit redundant to both keep references to the `Point`s that get passed in and to copy their coordinates too. You probably only need to do one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` should have variable parameters, not specific types. To support indexing you would need to implement additional special methods in Point, but I don't think it necessary in your code. Additionally, I would recommend names like `topleft` rather than `tL` as it will improve readability.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, bottomleft, topright, color):   # variable parameters
        self.bottomleft = bottomleft        # no need for self.bottomright_x
        self.topright = topright            # access x by rectangle.topright.x
        self.color = str(color)             # cast to a string
```

If you must, you can add assertions in init to ensure that the arguments passed into Rectangle are Points.

```
assert isinstance(bottomright, Point), 'Must enter a Point'
```